# OperationalError : (1054, "Unknown column 'snippets_snippet.owner_id' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

this is model.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers, get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
from pygments.formatters.html import HtmlFormatter
from pygments import highlight

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())


class Snippet(models.Model):
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code        = models.TextField()
    linenos     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language    = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style       = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)
    owner       = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
    highlighted = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lexer               = get_lexer_by_name(self.language)
        linenos             = self.linenos and 'table' or False
        options             = self.title and {'title': self.title} or {}
        formatter           = HtmlFormatter(style=self.style, linenos=linenos, full=True, **options)
        self.highlighted    = highlight(self.code, lexer, formatter)
        super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

and this is serializers.py

```
 class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets    = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model   = User
        fields  = ('id','username','snippets')
```

Whenever I access the client via the API, I get the following error:

> (1054, "Unknown column 'snippets_snippet.owner_id' in 'field list'")

i am already drop database and syscdb again but it same error.

can you help solve this problem?

Comment: The issue here is in your model, not DRF. Did you make any changes to the Snippet model recently and forget to migrate the database?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is old, but I was running through the same tutorial ([Django Rest Framework Tutorial #4](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/)) and encountered the same issue. I thought that I'd post the resolution to the issue in case someone else comes across this as well.

This error is telling you that the owner foreign key column does not exist in the snippets table. Likely this means that the `python manage.py migrate` step failed to create the column as expected on the snippets table.

The problem is that during the tutorial they want to add a table column after content has been entered. Doing so will result in warnings from django when you do the migrate. So instead of doing that they get get you to delete your database and the migrations file in the snippets app. (Note: Since this is just a tutorial and no real data is entered it's okay). However, if this is not done properly or (in my case) you're using MySQL (not sqlite) and the migration doesn't create the new field (the owner foreign key column in the snippets table) then this error occurs.

To fix it, (I'm using MySQL) I dropped the database and re-created it, then removed the migration files from snippets/migrations (as the tutorial suggests and leaving the migrations folder in place). Then did a full: `python manage.py makemigrations`, then `python manage.py migrate`. Then after that I confirmed within mysql that the tables were created with the new owner foreign key column.

The tutorial doesn't have much explanation around what they're doing with those commands. In my humble opinion. :) Hope that helps someone who encounters the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use your `UserSerializer` and set it to `readonly`

It should be

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        owner = serializers.UserSerializer(read_only=True)
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style','owner')
```

Comment: show error like this "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'readonly'" how?

Comment: but back again error "  

(1054, "Unknown column 'snippets_snippet.owner_id' in 'field list'")" how?

Comment: Also,in your `User` serializer you are using `model = User` but in Snippet model you have `owner       = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')`.  so `auth.User` is the same that `User`

Comment: thanks, but i am not really understand. can you tell me detail what should i change the code?